# Inner join VS some other method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql-server.I have a table looks like

```
StudentName   Class  score
Jim            a1     80
Ann            a1     83
Bill           a2     90
```

I want to select student whose score is above the average score in his/her class. Here is my code:

```
Select a.StudentName
From Table a
inner Join Table b
On a.class=b.class 
where a.score>(select avg(b.score) From b
group by class);
```

The inner join method looks odd to me.Is it correct please? Is there any better way to achieve that please?

Comment: You have all students in one table. Why do you need a join? A join is used to combine two (or more) tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you can limit your sub-query and take out the JOIN:

```
Select a.StudentName
From Table a
where a.score > (
    select avg(b.score) score 
    From Table b
    where b.class = a.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Don't I need join please? Should I define b?

Comment: No; you _can_ do it by joining to a subquery, but this is cleaner IMHO.  And b is defined inside the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
;with ClassAverages as (
  select Class, AVG(score) as AVGScore FROM Table GROUP BY Class
)
SELECT StudentName FROM Table student
INNER JOIN ClassAverages ON ClassAverages.Class=student.Class
WHERE student.score>ClassAverages.AVGScore
```

Comment: If I am using Oracle, can I use ;with xxx( ) for definition please?

Comment: I don't know that. How about you ask that in another question with an Oracle tag?